# When do you add の after a country name?

Tags: grammar, particle-の, adjectives

For example, why is it アメリカの映画 for American movie and フランス料理 for French food?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add の after a country name when you don't want to represent it as a category. For example, フランス料理 is understood as French cuisine, but フランスの料理 is understood as dishes in France which may include French cuisine.

Comment: thank you, this is helpful!